# How to block entering into one section in another place of program only?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have two sections of code:

```
section_a

# some code

section_b
```

I need to block the **section_a** only if the **section_b** is executed. The **section_a** can be executed by many threads if there is no block in the **section_b**.

When the **section_b** is started to be executed I need to send a signal to other threads not to enter to the **section_a** (to wait before it). And when last thread leaves the **section_a** the **section_b** must be executed.

If I use the conditional locking (threading.Condition.acquire(), threading.Condition.release()) to solve the problem I'm confused how to allow entering to a **section_a** by many threads simultaneously. When we call condition.acquire() before the **section_a** then other threads are blocked also to enter the section.

```
while True:

    condition.acquire() # other threads that would enter point_a can't do that after this acquire()
    #section_a, point_a
    condition.release()

# another place of a program
while True:
    condition.acquire() # I'd like threads can't enter section_a after this acquire, but not after acquire before point_a
    #section_b
    condition.release()
```

And I need to block the **section_b** if the **section_a** is executed by any thread.

Could you advise me the correct construction please?

Execuse me, I have no experience with multithreading. Probably there is an entirely another construction.

Comment: Is the reverse also true, can multiple threads execute inside section_b if none are in section_a?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson It's no matter. I made the update: "When the section_b is started..."

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SHLock` (shared lock) from [threading2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/threading2) which would seem to do exactly what you want.

It's `acquire` method takes a `shared` parameter, if it's passed in as `true`, you'll lock it in shared mode, if it's passed in as `false`, you'll lock it in exclusive mode.

In your example, you would call `acquire` in shared mode when entering section_a, which would let any amount of threads enter section_a. When you enter section_b, you'd lock in exclusive mode, which will prevent any simultaneous shared mode locks (ie anyone from entering section_a at the same time as you hold the lock)

Comment: The very good proposal. The one thing that confuse me is that the module uses threading module. Probably it works little slower. I don't know how stable (bugless) it works with many threads. But thank you, I consider your proposal. Probably I should see the **SHLock's** implementation in the module.